# Cone in Latex with right angles and Label

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new LaTex user and I have hard time plot the following shape in LaTex. I started the shape but I can't find way to finish it if you can help me please

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (3,0) node {$\mathcal{C}$};
    \draw (-2,2)--(0,0);
    \draw (3,1.5)--(0,0);
    \draw (-2,-2)--(0,0);
    \draw (3,-1.5)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the shape I am aiming to get if you can help me finish it please.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain a bit more the context of the figure. Is this a 3d figure? If so, there is the possibility to draw this in 3d.

Comment: @marmot Thank you. Yes it is 3d figure where the point X is projected to the Cone C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a bit hard to undo the projection, i.e. to guess the 3d coordinates from their projections on the screen. So most likely I got some wrong, yet this may serve as a start. I recommend using `tikz-3dplot` because it allows you to do orthographic projections from 3d to the screen. That is, you can adjust the view angles to your needs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{30}{20}{0}    
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw (0,0,0) node[dot,label=left:{$O$}] (O) {} 
        -- (0,0,5) node[pos=1.1] (A) {$A$}; % A=z
    \draw (O) -- (4,0,0) node[pos=1.1] (B) {$B$}; % B=x
    \draw (O) -- (0,5,0) node[pos=1.1] (C) {$C$}; % C=y
    \draw (0,0,1) -- ++ (0,1,0) -- ++ (0,0,-1);
    \draw[dotted,thick] (0,0,3) node[dot,label=right:{$\widetilde{\theta}$}]{} 
        -- (0,5,3) node[dot,label=above:{$X$}]{}; 
    \draw (0,0,4)-- ++ (0,1,0) -- ++ (0,0,-1);
    \draw (O) -- (0,-3,-3) node[pos=1.1]{$D$}; 
    \draw (1,0,0) -- ++ (0,{-1/sqrt(2)},{-1/sqrt(2)}) -- ++ (-1,0,0);
    \draw[dotted,thick] (1.5,0,0) node[dot,label=above:{$\widetilde{\theta}$}]{}
     -- ++ (0,-3,-3) node[dot,label=right:{$X$}]{}; 
    \draw (2.5,0,0) -- ++ (0,{-1/sqrt(2)},{-1/sqrt(2)}) -- ++ (-1,0,0);
    \path (B) -- (A) node[pos=0.3]{$\mathcal{C}$};
    \draw[dotted,thick] (O) -- (0,3,-3) node[dot,label=left:{$X$}]{};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw (0,0,0) node[dot,label=left:{$O$}] (O) {} 
        -- (0,0,5) node[pos=1.1] (A) {$A$}; % A=z
    \draw (O) -- (4,0,0) node[pos=1.1] (B) {$B$}; % B=x
    \draw (O) -- (0,5,0) node[pos=1.1] (C) {$C$}; % C=y
    \draw (0,0,1) -- ++ (0,1,0) -- ++ (0,0,-1);
    \draw (0,0,3) node[dot,label=right:{$Q$}] (Q) {} 
        -- (0,5,3) node[dot,label=above:{$P$}]{}; 
    \draw (0,0,4)-- ++ (0,1,0) -- ++ (0,0,-1);
    \draw (O) -- (0,-3,-3) node[pos=1.1]{$D$}; 
    \draw (1,0,0) -- ++ (0,{-1/sqrt(2)},{-1/sqrt(2)}) -- ++ (-1,0,0);
    \draw (1.5,0,0) node[dot,label=above right:{$R$}] (R) {}
     -- ++ (0,-3,-3) node[dot,label=right:{$S$}]{}; 
    \draw (2.5,0,0) -- ++ (0,{-1/sqrt(2)},{-1/sqrt(2)}) -- ++ (-1,0,0);
    \path (B) -- (A) node[pos=0.3]{$\mathcal{C}$};
    \draw (R) to[out=80,in=-40] (Q);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]